# How to config Django for Oracle RAC mode

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

We have two kinds of web servers. One is based on Java(tomcat + spring boot), while another is based on Python(Django).

Recently we changed db from normal Oracle to RAC mode, which our Java server can successfully connect to it by following config:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=177.177.50.112) (PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=177.177.50.113)(PORT=1521))(LOAD_BALANCE=NO)(FAILOVER=YES))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=aldb)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
```

However for Django server, we can't find a proper way to config such connection.   Anyone has experience to config Oracle RAC for Django?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I resolved this issue by not setting 'PORT' in Django config, but setting value of 'NAME' same as Java jdbc dsn string. Here is a example:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': '(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=177.177.50.112) (PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=177.177.50.113)(PORT=1521))(LOAD_BALANCE=NO)(FAILOVER=YES))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=aldb)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))'
    'USER':xxx,
    'PASSWORD':xxx
    }
}
```